# saving array to disk in a singleton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have a singleton which has an NSArray that is created when the first instance of the singleton is.  When should I save this array to disk, in dealloc method? I checked the Apple docs and its says you really shouldn't in dealloc but fails to say where. So am I meant to write to disk everytime the array is modified? This seems like a waste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should save state close to the time that state was changed. If the amount of state that you are saving is very small, then you could wait until application delegate -applicationWillResignActive: method gets called. Or you could have singleton register with NSNotificationCenter to observe UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification. And then save.

If your array will be very large, then you may wish to save less frequently. But you must also be mindful of how long it might take to write your array to disk. Depending on the circumstances under which your application resigns as active, you may not get much time to write to disk.

Do you have a good sense of the maximum amount of data that might need to be written? Is this constrained or is it open-ended?

Comment: Well everytime the user reorders cells in a tableView (and there are actually 2 NSArrays) the arrays in the singleton get updated to match, the user is likely to reorder more than one row at a time, but it will get called for every row moved, so I don't want the user to move a row, the app save to disk, the user move another row a millisecond later and have to save to disk again etc.

Comment: Is there any notion of the user committing recent changes, like a "Done" button? For that matter, is there a "Cancel" that would discard recent changes?

Comment: How could I've forgotten that? Why did I ask the question :)